# How to extract tar file that contains files with names with unicode characters using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, tarfile

I have a .tar.gz file that contains a file that has "unusual" unicode characters in its names (NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem). When I extract the archive using python 3's tarfile module, the file name is messed up (NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Fotanstvny.pem).

```
with tarfile.open(name='archive.tar.gz', mode='r:gz', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.extractall(targetFolder)
    file.close
```

I tried various encodings, but none of them managed to get the file name right.
I am running Windows.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure that the name if the archive is actually what your expect? Did you control it with a different tool, for example 7Zip?

Comment: What version of Windows and Python?  Windows 10 and Python 3.6 worked.  Created a .tar.gz using Python `tarfile` and `gzip` modules with that filename content and it extracted it fine.

Comment: Damn, seems like it already fails when packing. I did this with the command line version of 7zip.

Comment: If you can reliably display the broken contents and your expected output, this is still fixable in Python - with some code to run after the extraction takes place and rename the files properly. That is, if the chars are there, even if with the wrong encoding. If they are replaced by a placeholder or suppressed, nothing can be done.